# PrestaShop 1.6 show promotional products (blockspecials) from the current category

Tags: module, prestashop

after clicking on the categories above the list of products in this category, I would like to block the promotions of products from this category.

I currently have a module blockspecials hook in the category and I can copy / display random promotional products or all products on the promotion (as on the main page). I need products for promotions in this category which I will click, how to bite it?

```
if (Configuration::get('PS_CATALOG_MODE'))
            return;

        // We need to create multiple caches because the products are sorted randomly
        $random = date('Ymd').'|'.round(rand(1, max(Configuration::get('BLOCKSPECIALS_NB_CACHES'), 1)));

        if (!Configuration::get('BLOCKSPECIALS_NB_CACHES') || !$this->isCached('blockspecials.tpl', $this->getCacheId('blockspecials|'.$random)))
        {
            if (!($special = Product::getRandomSpecial((int)$params['cookie']->id_lang)) && !Configuration::get('PS_BLOCK_SPECIALS_DISPLAY'))
                return;

            $this->smarty->assign(array(
                'special' => $special,
                'priceWithoutReduction_tax_excl' => Tools::ps_round($special['price_without_reduction'], 2),
                'mediumSize' => Image::getSize(ImageType::getFormatedName('medium')),
            ));
        }

        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'blockspecials.tpl', (Configuration::get('BLOCKSPECIALS_NB_CACHES') ? $this->getCacheId('blockspecials|'.$random) : null));
```

how i can change function `getRandomSpecial` to function display promotion products from current category?

I'm not advance with Prestashop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify a query(first $sql) in the function Product::getRandomSpecial this way

```
$sql = 'SELECT product_shop.id_product, IFNULL(product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute,0) id_product_attribute
                FROM
                `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_reductions` pr,
                `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p
                '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').'
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` category_product
                    ON (p.`id_product` = category_product.`id_product`)
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute_shop` product_attribute_shop
                    ON (p.`id_product` = product_attribute_shop.`id_product` AND product_attribute_shop.`default_on` = 1 AND product_attribute_shop.id_shop='.(int)$context->shop->id.')
                WHERE p.id_product=pr.id_product AND category_product.`id_category` = '.(int)Tools::getValue('id_category').' AND (pr.id_product_attribute = 0 OR product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute = pr.id_product_attribute) AND product_shop.`active` = 1
                    '.$sql_groups.'
                '.($front ? ' AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "catalog")' : '').'
                ORDER BY RAND()';
```

then replace next line

```
$result = Db::getInstance()->getRow($sql);
```

with

```
$results = Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql);
```

add new variable

```
$specialProducts = array();
```

and then embrace all code until the condition closing brace with a code

```
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        if (!$id_product = $result['id_product']) {
            return false;
        }
        // no group by needed : there's only one attribute with cover=1 for a given id_product + shop
        $sql = 'SELECT p.*, product_shop.*, stock.`out_of_stock` out_of_stock, pl.`description`, pl.`description_short`,
            pl.`link_rewrite`, pl.`meta_description`, pl.`meta_keywords`, pl.`meta_title`, pl.`name`, pl.`available_now`, pl.`available_later`,
                    p.`ean13`, p.`upc`, image_shop.`id_image` id_image, il.`legend`,
                    DATEDIFF(product_shop.`date_add`, DATE_SUB("'.date('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00",
                    INTERVAL '.(Validate::isUnsignedInt(
                    Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT')
                ) ? Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT') : 20).'
                        DAY)) > 0 AS new
                FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang` pl ON (
                    p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`
                    AND pl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl').'
                )
                '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').'
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image_shop` image_shop
                    ON (image_shop.`id_product` = p.`id_product` AND image_shop.cover=1 AND image_shop.id_shop='.(int)$context->shop->id.')
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image_lang` il ON (image_shop.`id_image` = il.`id_image` AND il.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.')
                '.Product::sqlStock('p', 0).'
        WHERE p.id_product = '.(int)$id_product;
        $row = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getRow($sql);
        if (!$row) {
            return false;
        }
        $row['id_product_attribute'] = (int)$result['id_product_attribute'];

        $specialProducts[] = Product::getProductProperties($id_lang, $row);
    }

    return $specialProducts;
```

then modify a module file modules/blockspecials/blockspecials.php with the next changes. Find code

```
if (!Configuration::get('BLOCKSPECIALS_NB_CACHES') || !$this->isCached('blockspecials.tpl', $this->getCacheId('blockspecials|'.$random)))
    {
        if (!($special = Product::getRandomSpecial((int)$params['cookie']->id_lang)) && !Configuration::get('PS_BLOCK_SPECIALS_DISPLAY'))
            return;

        $this->smarty->assign(array(
            'special' => $special,
            'priceWithoutReduction_tax_excl' => Tools::ps_round($special['price_without_reduction'], 2),
            'mediumSize' => Image::getSize(ImageType::getFormatedName('medium')),
        ));
    }
```

and replace it with

```
if (!Configuration::get('BLOCKSPECIALS_NB_CACHES') || !$this->isCached('blockspecials.tpl', $this->getCacheId('blockspecials|'.$random)))
    {
        if (!($specials = Product::getRandomSpecial((int)$params['cookie']->id_lang)) && !Configuration::get('PS_BLOCK_SPECIALS_DISPLAY'))
            return;

        $this->smarty->assign(array(
            'specials' => $specials,
            'mediumSize' => Image::getSize(ImageType::getFormatedName('medium')),
        ));
    }
```

also you neet to modify themes/your_theme/modules/blockspecials/blockspecials.tpl, find

```
{if $special}
    <ul>
        <li class="clearfix">
            <a class="products-block-image" href="{$special.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                <img 
                class="replace-2x img-responsive" 
                src="{$link->getImageLink($special.link_rewrite, $special.id_image, 'small_default')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" 
                alt="{$special.legend|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" 
                title="{$special.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" />
            </a>
            <div class="product-content">
                <h5>
                    <a class="product-name" href="{$special.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{$special.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                        {$special.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
                    </a>
                </h5>
                {if isset($special.description_short) && $special.description_short}
                    <p class="product-description">
                        {$special.description_short|strip_tags:'UTF-8'|truncate:40}
                    </p>
                {/if}
                <div class="price-box">
                    {if !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
                        <span class="price special-price">
                            {if !$priceDisplay}
                                {displayWtPrice p=$special.price}{else}{displayWtPrice p=$special.price_tax_exc}
                            {/if}
                        </span>
                         {if $special.specific_prices}
                            {assign var='specific_prices' value=$special.specific_prices}
                            {if $specific_prices.reduction_type == 'percentage' && ($specific_prices.from == $specific_prices.to OR ($smarty.now|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' <= $specific_prices.to && $smarty.now|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >= $specific_prices.from))}
                                <span class="price-percent-reduction">-{$specific_prices.reduction*100|floatval}%</span>
                            {/if}
                        {/if}
                         <span class="old-price">
                            {if !$priceDisplay}
                                {displayWtPrice p=$special.price_without_reduction}{else}{displayWtPrice p=$priceWithoutReduction_tax_excl}
                            {/if}
                        </span>
                        {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$special type="price"}
                    {/if}
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

and replace with

```
{if $specials}
    <ul>
      {foreach from=$specials item='special'}
        <li class="clearfix">
            <a class="products-block-image" href="{$special.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                <img 
                class="replace-2x img-responsive" 
                src="{$link->getImageLink($special.link_rewrite, $special.id_image, 'small_default')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" 
                alt="{$special.legend|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" 
                title="{$special.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" />
            </a>
            <div class="product-content">
                <h5>
                    <a class="product-name" href="{$special.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{$special.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                        {$special.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
                    </a>
                </h5>
                {if isset($special.description_short) && $special.description_short}
                    <p class="product-description">
                        {$special.description_short|strip_tags:'UTF-8'|truncate:40}
                    </p>
                {/if}
                <div class="price-box">
                    {if !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
                        <span class="price special-price">
                            {if !$priceDisplay}
                                {displayWtPrice p=$special.price}{else}{displayWtPrice p=$special.price_tax_exc}
                            {/if}
                        </span>
                         {if $special.specific_prices}
                            {assign var='specific_prices' value=$special.specific_prices}
                            {if $specific_prices.reduction_type == 'percentage' && ($specific_prices.from == $specific_prices.to OR ($smarty.now|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' <= $specific_prices.to && $smarty.now|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >= $specific_prices.from))}
                                <span class="price-percent-reduction">-{$specific_prices.reduction*100|floatval}%</span>
                            {/if}
                        {/if}
                         <span class="old-price">
                            {if !$priceDisplay}
                                {displayWtPrice p=$special.price_without_reduction}{else}{displayWtPrice p=$priceWithoutReduction_tax_excl}
                            {/if}
                        </span>
                        {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$special type="price"}
                    {/if}
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
  {/foreach}
    </ul>
```

The above manipulations have to help you implement your task

Comment: I have function  "public function hookInCategory($params)" so inside i should write query $sql? and LEFT JOIN in date base and add new condition in this function?

Comment: No, you need to modify Product::getRandomSpecial function and then you will get proper result, and there is already exist that $sql which you need to modify

Comment: I don't know where Product::getRandomSpecial function is? You mean in function hookName($params)?

Comment: This part of the code is in the main product class root/classes/Product.php (line 2391in my case)

Comment: ok I have and changed the query slq, so now LEFT JOIN i should add in database or in this function but where? sorry for my small knowledge :)

Comment: Just use that code, which I've provided(the large one) and, replace the old $sql(the first one in the getRandomSpecial) with it

Comment: I replaced (first $SQL) and did not work it, all time i see random product and only one - I would like see all produkcts in this category on promotion

Comment: Ok, I missed that you want to get all products so I'll modify the answer

Comment: there is a little problem, all it works good but when i clicked different categorys, refresh pages and general move on category i see bug: products from other category

Comment: if you have cache turned on try to add a new parameter to the cache identifier $this->getCacheId('blockspecials|'.$random.Tools::getValue('id_category'))

Comment: it not works when i refreshed few times, products change sometimes

Comment: Are you sure that those products are not from the current category? Because now they have random order without limit to show. Maybe you can provide a demo link&

Comment: work on localhost and i'm sure products are changing from other categorys, maybe with this is problem: "Notice: Undefined index: hook in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\cache\smarty\compile\5b\b2\71\5bb271fae1d7b66db48084661793c09bbc91bf88.file.hook.tpl.php on line 90"
i have this from a certain time (before post here) but it is about cache

Comment: Checked it out one more time, it works absolutely expectably. But keep in mind that it shows all products that are related to the category

Comment: it is some problem with cache because when cache turned, sometimes product changing when cache turned off all works good. So to not turn cache? or without localhost will be ok?

Comment: try to replace $this->getCacheId('blockspecials|'.$random) with $this->getCacheId('blockspecials|'.$random.'|'.Tools::getValue('id_category') in the blockspecial.php(in the if and in the return) it must help, but if not then remove cache from module. First: remove condition if (!Configuration::get('BLOCKSPECIALS_NB_CACHES') || !$this->isCached('blockspecials.tpl', $this->getCacheId('blockspecials|'.$random))) and second remove third parameter from $this->display function call

Comment: it is a problem with return <code>return $this->display(__FILE__, 'blockspecials.tpl', (Configuration::get('BLOCKSPECIALS_NB_CACHES') ?
$this->getCacheId('blockspecials|'.$random.'|'.Tools::getValue('id_category'))));</code>
syntax error, unexpected ')' but all brackets all ok

Comment: It is incorrect. If you want to have a cache then use return $this->display(__FILE__, 'blockspecials.tpl', (Configuration::get('BLOCKSPECIALS_NB_CACHES') ? $this->getCacheId('blockspecials|'.$random.'|'.Tools::getValue('id_category')) : null)); if you dont then use return $this->display(__FILE__, 'blockspecials.tpl'); In your code you have removed only one part of condition so you get an error